# Tracking down which app makes HTTP requests

Tags: security, networking, logging

After configuring my Galaxy S4 (Android 4.4.2) phone to use a proxy server for debugging an app, I noticed that other apps on my device were making some suspicious HTTP calls.  I would like to track down what app is doing this.

Unfortunately, the request itself didn't have any clues... it only contained a generic `User-Agent` header:

```
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SPH-L720 Build/KOT49H)
```

The response was also generic, and not related to anything I have knowingly installed.

Is there a way to log apps making HTTP requests on my Android device?

Comment: @DanHulme The answer on the question you linked to isn't appropriate in my case.  I'm not looking for network connections, I'm looking for information from HTTP requests.  In addition, I have considered running a packet capture over time but there isn't enough storage on my SD card to capture very long.

Comment: In that case, [edit] your question to say what information you want to capture. All you asked for is which app is making requests.

Comment: @DanHulme Yes... which app is making **HTTP requests**, not just general network connections.  I've edited the title to make it more clear.

Comment: HTTP is just one level above TCP, so use netstat (as described in that answer) and check outgoing TCP connections to port 80.